# Does the +1 bonus from the Improved Pact Weapon warlock invocation stack with the 2d6 extra damage from the Flame Tongue magic weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, damage, warlock, eldritch-invocations

To build up from [this similar question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132299/does-the-improved-pact-weapon-eldritch-invocation-grant-a-1-to-magical-pact-wea), does the warlock's +1 bonus from the Improved Pact Weapon eldritch invocation stack with optional bonuses, i.e. *flame tongue* when activated does 2d6 extra fire damage.

The relevant text for this:

Improved Pact Weapon:

> In addition, the weapon gains a +1 bonus to its attack and damage rolls, unless it is a magic weapon that already has a bonus to those rolls.

Flame Tongue:

> While the sword is ablaze, it deals an extra 2d6 fire damage to any target it hits.

There is no dispute between the +1 to hit, so I am confident in this bonus being applied.
The issue is instead with the damage.

When the *flame tongue* is not ablaze, it would do x+1 (where x is the base damage). However, when ablaze, will it do x+2d6+1 damage? Or just x+2d6 damage?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Your Pact weapon will deal X+1(slashing/bludgeoning/piercing) +2d6(fire) damage.

You quoted all the relevant rules: the description of the [Improved Pact Weapon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#ClassFeatures) says that you gain a +1 bonus to attack rolls and damage, *unless it is a magic weapon that already has a bonus to those rolls*.

A [*Flame Tongue*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/flame-tongue) has no such bonus, it "simply" adds 2d6 fire damage when it is ablaze: hence the requirements for Improved Pact Weapon are met and the weapon will deal X+1 + 2d6 total damage, being the first X+1 of the weapon damage type and the latter 2d6 of fire type.

Comment: So the 1d8 slashing of a flametongue longsword is the "damage roll," and because the 2d6 fire is a separate roll, it doesn't count as a bonus to the damage roll?

Comment: @BillThePlatypus Sorry, I do not understand what you're asking there...

Comment: @BillThePlatypus: no, flametongue's 2d6 is also part of the whole attack's "damage roll", and does get doubled on crit.

Comment: @Bill If a weapon deals multiple types of damage, all the dice together are considered [a single damage roll](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/130244)